# What does 'down' mean in soccer?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "down" mean in soccer term?

- Pérez is busy down the inside left channel again a moment later. He forces a corner, then heads the delivery just over the bar.

Comment: It’s just a plain preposition indicating direction. No special meaning.

Comment: @Jim you mean it's like a lower possition? This is soccer, so I don't see there is a lower movement.

Comment: I believe "down" also carries a meaning of "deep" with it .  .. but I also suspect that "up" might also be understood to be the same ... with the opposite to both "down" and "up" being "back" .  "Downfield" in american football means towards your opponents goal ... upfield would be relative to the person downfield and backfield would be behind original position

Answer (score 1):

As someone who has watched/listened to/read about football for the last 20 years, "down" in this sense generally signifies a movement towards the opposing goal on an attack, or away from one's own goal in a defensive move.

This is illustrated in the phrases "down the wing" (i.e. on the left- or right-hand side of the pitch, towards the opposing goal) and, conversely, to "hoof it downfield" (for a goalkeeper or defender to kick the ball with some strength away from their area towards the opposing goal, to clear the ball), and you might describe a player as "causing havoc down the right/left", meaning they were a constant threat on the respective side of the pitch.

You can see it [here](http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/live/football/40955802/), from a BBC match report:

> Fabregas tries to make progress **down the right**, and the ball comes off Ayoze Perez for a corner.

Or for "down the left", [here](http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/43267240/):

> He was the catalyst for the Blues' second goal, cutting Palace open **down the left**.

And [two](http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/41683715/) [uses](http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/42205575/) of "downfield" to mean 'away from one's own team's goal':

> When they came steaming **downfield**, Dembele curled a precise shot around the advancing Laidlaw for the fourth.
>
> Misplaced pass followed misplaced pass. Aimless punt **downfield** followed aimless punt **downfield**.

Oddly "upfield", rather than having the opposite meaning, can also signify an attacking movement, usually from a defensive position, e.g. in [these](http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/41683732/) [two](http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/41301955/) articles:

> Those supporters were soon dealt another blow as Stephen Robinson's side broke **upfield** and scored a second.
>
> Everton did not have runners in wide positions busting a gut to get **upfield**, or a centre-forward who could stretch the pitch.

As you can see from the use of 'break' and 'busting a gut to get upfield', 'upfield' seems to suggest an attack that starts close to the attacking team's goal where this is the desired emphasis.